# Installing Microsoft Report Builder 3.0 silently fails

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

Running from an Admin elevated cmd prompt in Windows 10 Pro

Doing a verbose logged install

> msiexec /i ReportBuilder3.msi /lv log.txt

silently fails/stops after the following log entries

`=== Logging started: 17/09/2018  15:01:27 ===
MSI (c) (08:30) [15:01:27:053]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: PatchPackage 
MSI (c) (08:30) [15:01:27:053]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (c) (08:30) [15:01:27:053]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding UILevel property. Its value is '5'.
MSI (c) (08:30) [15:01:27:053]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0`

Investigating using Systinternals Process Monitor shows trying to get a registry key immediately before the install silently fails

> Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\AppCompat

The msiexec process stays in memory and has to be closed using Task Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Give the installer what it is looking for and save your self hours of wasted time

TEMPORARILY adding a registry key for the 64 bit regedit allowed the install to complete

> Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\AppCompat\DisablePca DWORD=1